# How to move out of function

Tags: python, function, exit

i am novice to python and i have stuck at one point, though its a simple program
I have used 'Return False' to move out of the function but i want to move out of my function completely. How it can be done.
Also if i want to run this script from python shell, how it can be done.

```
def menu():
    print "calculator using functions"
    print "Choose your option:"
    print " "
    print "1) Addition"
    print "2) Subtraction"
    print "3) Multiplication"
    print "4) Division"
    print "5) Quit calculator.py"
    print " "
    return input ("Choose your option: ")


def add(a,b):
    print a, "+", b, "=", a + b
    print " Do you want to continue: "
    decide=raw_input("yes or no: ")
    if decide== "no" or decide== 'n':
        print(" You have exited ")
        return False
    elif decide=='yes' or decide== 'y':
        menu()
    else:
        print "wrong choice!!!"
        return False

# this subtracts two numbers given
def sub(a,b):
    print b, "-", a, "=", b - a

# this multiplies two numbers given
def mul(a,b):
    print a, "*", b, "=", a * b

# this divides two numbers given
def div(a,b):
    print a, "/", b, "=", a / b


loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        add(input("Add first No: "),input("Add second No: "))
    elif choice == 2:
        sub(input("Add first No: "),input("Add second No: "))
    elif choice == 3:
        mul(input("Add first No: "),input("Add second No: "))
    elif choice == 4:
        div(input("Add first No: "),input("Add second No: "))
    elif choice == 5:
        loop = 0

print "End of program!"
```

Comment: In the long run you'll want to restructure your program. `add` calls `menu` which might call `add` which calls `menu` and so on. Functions are not a kind of secret labels for a non-existing `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `exit`. It exits from the program.

```
import sys

def spam():
    .
    .
    .
    if some_condition:
        sys.exit(0) # exits from the program
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: exit closes the shell but i just want to move out my function or program and then run my program from shell only

Comment: move out of my function? how is that different from return?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to explicitly `return` anything to exit a function. When the interpreter reaches the end of the function block, the function exits.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line type:

python myprogram.py

to run the program from prompt, if you want to use a specific python shell (other than bash or cmd) then you need to look to the documentation of that specific shell (e.g http://www.dreampie.org/).

To exit from a function use:

```
return
```

To exit from a program use:

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: As note, you can also exit comfortably by using `raise SystemExit`